# Should I hardcode TLS certificates in arduino

Tags: ssl, mqtt, x509certificate, esp8266

I could connect my `ESP8266` board to my MQTT server over TLS. Everything works fine.

There is only one question (as I'm a beginner with encryption): Should I hard code `CA.crt`, `client.crt` and `client.key` on the board??

As I know, if my certificates expire, I have to purchase another certificate, meaning my boards won't work anymore (I sell them). Can I securely ask server for these files every time?

EDIT:

This question was closed because it was opinion-based. OK, give me an opinion! I have no idea to handle my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We can't answer this for you, only you know the details how how/where the device will be deployed. This will factor into what is acceptable

What I will say is that it is possible to do [Over the Air](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ota_updates/readme.html) updates with ESP8266 so you can push code updates that could include updated certificate fingerprints if needed or you can not include an actual CA certificate to verify the broker certificate.

As for client certificates, these don't need to be issued by a public CA so you have full control over their expiry time, so it's perfectly reasonable to set a life longer than the expected life of the device.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir. I'm a little bit confused. For a secure connection, I need 3 files. ca.crt, client.key and client.crt. On the MQTT config file, I set all 3. in the client side, I have to hardcode them all. IF I HAVE TO HARD CODE MY KEYS, HOW DOES CHROME CONNECTS TO A WEBSITE WITHOUT HAVING THESE KEYS??? What about fingerprints? How am I supposed to use them? I don't use any in my current implementation. (I'm begginer with encryption).

Comment: My server is self-signed "right now", but I'm going to set up a real server when the project is done.

Comment: Most of these questions are not directly related to the original question. You need to go read about the difference between TLS Server Authentication vs TLS Mutual Authentication (under most situation only TLS Server Authentication is done, in which case the client only needs a CA cert to verify the server).

Comment: It's more than a week which I'm looking for anything that explains these, and all courses explain stuff in their own way differently. I can't get the logic behind it. Do you know any website/youtube video/course that can help me?